# How to edit the terminal without clearing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The way I usually edit the terminal is by writing:

```
Import os
While "something":
   "Do something"
   Lambda: os.system("cls")
   print("result")
```

For clarification, I don't want to clear the console, I want to edit it directly so I can make a similar effect to the spinning line `('|','/','-','|','-','\')`.

Comment: hi @gamers-beware, what is your question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write('\b ')` will move the cursor back and replace the text with an empty space.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - it's not possible due to the nature of how text console works. It always prints text. If you need to have a static text and an ability to edit it, you have to keep initial text in memory, edit it and re-print it again by clearing previous text on the screen.